# Can't pass coordinates through localstorage

Tags: javascript, google-maps, local-storage, coordinates, sessionstorage

I'm trying to make a Google Maps application, where you can enter you location in an input and then get redirected to another page with a map that shows your location.
The problem is that when I'm saving the coordinates in a localstorage on one Javascript file its not able to read it out on the other one.
 Any ideas?

Heres my Code

Saving data:

```
 var location = document.getElementById('location-input').value;
axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
    params:{
        address:location,
        key:'AIzaSyBsOGGokaWGD3m5y4uYYG_sv7U1T9nZ5HI'
    }
})
.then(function(response) {
    // Log full response
    console.log(response);

    var lat = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
    var lng = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

    sessionStorage.setItem('lat', lat);
    sessionStorage.setItem('lng', lng)

    console.log(lat)
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
})`
```

Retrieving data:

```
function initMap(){
var lat = sessionStorage.getItem('lat');
var lng = sessionStorage.getItem('lng')
console.log(lat)
})}
```

I want to add that passing a number directly or passing a word is no problem.

Comment: Any errors in the JavaScript console? Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: nope no errors.

Answer (score 2):

`lat` & `lng` are functions of a [`google.maps.LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/coordinates#LatLng).
Call them to get the value:

```
var lat = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat();
var lng = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng();
```

**live proof of concept:**

- [example store](http://www.geocodezip.com/SO_20180730_coordThruLocalStorage_store.html)
- [example retrieve](http://www.geocodezip.com/SO_20180730_coordThruLocalStorage_retrieve.html)

Comment: It still doesnt work. I only get null as a response even though Its able to log the output on the first webpage.

Comment: It works for me: [store](http://www.geocodezip.com/SO_20180730_coordThruLocalStorage_store.html), [retrieve](http://www.geocodezip.com/SO_20180730_coordThruLocalStorage_retrieve.html).  If these working examples don't help, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

better to encode your data before pssing them

```
var coord = JSON.stringify({
  lat :  response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat();
  lng  : response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng();
});
sessionStorage.setItem('coord', coord);
```

Comment: now i always get the coordinates of my the town from my first input. it never changes